# How do I determine what's making the web server so slow (Apache)

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, php, mysql, windows-server

I'm running Apache 2.4 (64bit) on a Windows server. It also uses MySQL 5.7 on the same server.

It has been very, very slow recently to come up, but when I look at the access logs, there are very few connections. I do see some attempts to get at phpmyadmin and other scripts (none of which exist) but not hundreds of those requests.

When I looked at the memory httpd and Mysql were consuming, they were both very low and steady:

```
#tasklist
httpd  50,003 K
mysql  205,000 K
```

Restarting mysql made no difference in performance or memory. But after restarting httpd, it now takes 39,000 K in memory and the site is now responsive again.

I've looked in the logs and don't see anything out of the ordinary. So how do i determine what is making the site so non-responsive?

**EDIT** I don't know if it will help, but I'm going to try this fix: ( mentioned here: https://superuser.com/a/627251/223518 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21033620/857025 )

Add the following to httpd.conf and restart httpd:

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

Comment: in all likelihood, it is your application, not the server that is causing the problem. what application are you serving over httpd?

Comment: @FrankThomas Just a website written in PHP. It's a very simple site.

Comment: I'd compare how fast the site serves static HTML files with how fast it serves a PHP file. You might try renaming a file that contains only HTML as a PHP file and see if it gets served slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `top` to list the current processes. You can sort by memory usage by pressing `M` (caps M) or by CPU usage by pressing `P` (caps P). Once you have identified the memory hog you can use the PID and COMMAND columns to identify the errant process.

Comment: top is a linux program

Comment: DOH! http://superuser.com/questions/176624/linux-top-command-for-windows-powershell references how to use PowerShell to emulate `top`.  Sorry, I'll read the questions more thoroughly next time.

Comment: ok, but if you read my post you'll also see that I already checked memory usage.